# What is the best way to have multiple components of a single type?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, components, aframe, amazon-ecs

For example I want to generalize my existing [trigger box component](https://github.com/Utopiah/aframe-triggerbox-component/blob/master/aframe-triggerbox-component.js).

I use currently it the following way

```
<a-camera triggerbox="triggereventname: mytriggerbox"></a-camera>
```

but instead I would like to be able to have

```
<a-camera triggerbox1="triggereventname: SmTB; x0: -20; y0: 0; z0: -20; "
triggerbox2="triggereventname: LgTB; width: 10; height: 10; depth: 10;"
></a-camera>
```

and have multiple trigger boxes, not just one, attached to the camera (or any other element).

Unfortunately all the solutions I think of (e.g. re-registering the component with different names for each instance) are horribly ugly. What is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: Apparently version 0.3.0 will allow having multiple components of a single type by doing for  my-component__id1 ‘my-component__id2‘. cf e.g. with sound https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/test/cursor/index.html#L46 . Components have to opt in and handle multiplicity https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/sound.js#L19 (via Dmarcos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it will be part of the component API in 0.3.0:

Here is the master documentation: https://aframe.io/docs/master/core/component.html#multiple-instancing